# how to parse data of website with constant URL

Tags: php, parsing

I want to parse data of a website like this: *(website is a dictionary - search website)*

When I search on website, the website does not refresh, the result will be shown, and the URL does not change.

Now I want to know is it possible to using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) or cURL or anything else for parsing the website ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Check the ajax calls that are triggered in the console and try to fetch these urls instead using the correct method and data.
2. Disable javascript and see if it still works. If it does, you will see what you need to get.

However, if the site does not want you to get the data, they can prevent it and / or block you if you make too many requests.

Comment: I did the number of 2 (unfortunately was not helpful). I want to know about number 1 more ... how can i check ajax ? When I inspect element the website, I see 2 `.js` file. I open them and see very tumultuous js codes. Can guide me more ? tnx

Comment: @stack You need to open the console in your browser tools and check what files are requested when you do things on the site. There is no need to go through their js.