# How to detect files are requested (AJAX) via browser's console?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, console

This question is linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839615/how-to-parse-data-of-website-with-constant-url). When I open console, It is too vague for me. In fact I want to know, how can I detect files are requested in AJAX via browser's console (Google Chrome).

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you post your question instead of giving link?

Comment: @AmneshGoel posting my question ?! I don't got it ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the network tab and filter by XHR type
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network
*the image explains better*
[image: the network tab]

Comment: that page doesn't have any ajax requests, check all to see everything has been loaded

Comment: Really?! did you click on bottom and see the results ? Then what happen when I click on bottom ? Is it possible to parsing that web page ?

Comment: I didn't see any XHR requests, did you?

Comment: No I did not too!! So I want to know is it possible to pars this site ?! (by cURL or [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) or anything else ..). I really need to all data on the site.